# Selenium doesn't start webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

**versions**

```
"nightwatch": "^0.9.16" 
"chromedriver": "^2.30.1"
"selenium-server-standalone-jar": "^3.4.0"
```

I'm using nightwatch but that sh
I also tried with

I'm using [nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/) to run Selenium in [this repo](https://github.com/goldylucks/ci-workshop) and I've tried with chrome and firefox drivers, no luck on either.

I have [selenium standalone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-server-standalone-jar) and [chromedriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver) packages, and I know the path is right on `nightwatch.conf.js`:

```
const jar = require('selenium-server-standalone-jar')
console.log(jar.path) // logs /home/goldylucks/apps/ci-workshop/node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver')
console.log(chromedriver.path) // logs /home/goldylucks/apps/ci-workshop/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver

'selenium': {
  'start_process': true,
  'server_path': jar.path,
  'log_path': '',
  'port': 4444,
  'cli_args': {
    'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromedriver.path,
    'webdriver.ie.driver': '',
  },
},

'test_settings': {
  'chrome': {
    'desiredCapabilities': {
      'browserName': 'chrome',
      'javascriptEnabled': true,
      'acceptSslCerts': true,
    },
  },
```

yet when I run the test it times out and hangs:

```
$ yarn e2e:ui
yarn e2e:ui v0.24.6
$ nightwatch -e chrome 
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  12936

[App E2e Ui] Test Suite
===========================
 ✖ Timed out while waiting for element <body> to be present for 5000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
    at Object.before (/home/goldylucks/apps/ci-workshop/test/ui/app.e2e-ui.js:9:8)
```

I tried it with the following combinations:
1. with the express server which serves the app on another terminal
2. without the express server
3. each of the above with chromedriver manually started at another terminal (I really don't think it should matter and that I should do this, just wanted to be thorough ...)

running the chromedriver manually yields the following and hangs:

```
$ node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

I also tried running with firefox and it didn't work, which leads me to believe the problem is deeper than the chromedriver, i.e. related to selenium interacting with nightwatch.

Answer (score 2):

I recall this happening a while back. I think it was that a previous instance Selenium had not <del>closed</del> *freed* port 4444 when shutting down. Try shutting down selenium and restarting.

To do that, open the following webpage manually, in the browser of your choice.
http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer

Then try running the script again as normal.

Comment: I get a selenium message: `Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.` what do u mean hasn't closed port 4444? it should be open, that's where the tests run

Comment: Right, I think it's in use by another instance of Selenium. I am saying it did not shut down. Nightwatch handles the startup and shutdown of Selenium for each test script.

Comment: I have also edited my answer above for clarification.

Comment: yes, added my versions at the top of the question, thanks